# Understanding Java Generics sub-typing

Tags: java, generics

[image: Subtypes]

Picture from http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/subtyping.html

How can `List<? super Number>` be sub type of `List<? super Integer>` ?

Comment: Where did you get that picture and what do the arrows mean? What do you mean by "subtype"? In Java there are no "types", only classes.

Comment: @m0skit0 `In Java there are no "types", only classes` it is true and the same time it is not true. There is no structure as `type` in Java, but variables can have their types, like `"foo"` is instance of `String` *class*, but at the same time its *type* is also `Object`, `Serializable`, `Comparable` and `CharSequence`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That is because a `List<? super Integer>` is capture convertible to all the lists that can be capture converted from `List<? super Number>`.

Let's see what all types are capture-convertible from `List<? super Number>`:

- `List<Number>`
- `List<Object>`
- `List<Serializable>`

A `List<? super Integer>` is capture-convertible to all the above types. So you can safely assign a `List<? super Number>` to a `List<? super Integer>`, without any compiler error.

Just in case you're thinking [what is](http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/java/library/j-jtp04298/index.html) [capture-conversion](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-5.html#jls-5.1.10), it means, you can assign a `List<Number>` to a `List<? super Number>`.

Answer (score 1):

Any `super` of `Number` is also a `super` of `Integer`.

As mentioned below the instanceof example I gave would not compile. It probably wasn't the best way of showing it.

Comment: Isn't `instanceof` evaluated at runtime?

Comment: That `instanceof` code wouldn't compile. Second operand of `instanceof` cannot be parameterized type or bounded wildcard type.